# Can I run Xampp alongside tomcat on the same server

Tags: windows, apache, tomcat, xampp

I have a webapp running in tomcat, i need to build a website in joomla and would like to install xampp on that same server (Windows Server 2012) to run the site and the database, is this possible without affecting the Tomcat installation?

Answer (score 0):

Sure it is. Tomcat uses port 8080 by default, while the Apache web server uses 80.